# Ensuring String inequality in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called flights that includes fields called *origin* and *destination* which are the airport codes referenced from the airports table and which i have defined as CHAR(3). I want to be able to insert records where for obvious reasons the values in the origin and departure columns cannot be the same.
How do i accomplish this with an INSERT INTO TABLE SQL statement?

Comment: Add an unique index on both columns

Comment: @Mihai That won't prevent a flight from `ABC` to `ABC` in the DB. Validation for this should be done at the application level.

Comment: so if i had to accomplish this in php i suppose i would have to use a built in function that compares two input strings?

Comment: @Jockfaire Don't overcomplicate it. `if($origin == $destination) { // show an error }`

Comment: @ceejayoz. Thanks.I'll try your suggestion after the trigger suggestion by barudo. My preference is to enforce this in the DB but use php as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this in MySQL is using a trigger.

Other databases support a `check` constraint where you can say `check (origin <> destination)`.  MySQL accepts this syntax but unfortunately does not enforce the constraint.

You can also do this at the application layer.

Comment: I was thinking that i could have accomplished this in the DB rather than in the application.

Comment: so i suppose the same would hold true for comparing times using the TIME datatype??

Comment: @Jockfaire . . . `check` constraints are not implemented, regardless of the type of the columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `travels_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `travels` FOR EACH  ROW BEGIN
 DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF NEW.source=NEW.destination THEN
        set msg = "Error: You can't have same source and destination";
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;
END;
```

What it does is prevent the insert from occuring if source and destination are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll give this trigger a go (providing that phpMyAdmin will allow me) and report back on my findings.